# How can I measure the CPU time a Clojure function takes to execute?

Tags: clojure

I have seen profiling macros for Clojure but they all seem to use elapsed time. Is there any way to get the CPU time taken?

Comment: Does https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium give you what you need?

Comment: don't remember criterium giving cpu time, but it is awfully more reliable than just using (time "..")

Comment: @jim-downing +1 for reference to criterium

Answer (score 4):

Not seen such a solution.

However, you can probably achieve it with the [java.lang.management](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/package-summary.html) Java package which supports management / monitoring of the JVM.

In particular, the [ThreadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCPUTime()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getCurrentThreadCpuTime%28%29) sounds like it would do what you want.

Normally however I would just try and run my benchmark in an uncontested environment (i.e. one where it can get 100% CPU) and make the simplyfying assumption that elapsed time is approximately equal to CPU time. Then you can use the usual Clojure benchmarking tools, e.g. [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium).

Comment: I guess I could use  ThreadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCPUTime although since I'm using Clojure it uses thread pools for refs which kind of makes the calculation invalid. Is this a correct assumption I'm making though of usinf multiple threads?

Comment: I think it depends on what exactly you are trying to measure - a specific thread or all threads in the application?